# tkinter pack doesn't expand through whole area

Tags: python, tkinter

Having issues packing two frames to get an expected outcome as defined below:

Frame 1 to have a width of 150 and scale on Y value, color of blue.
Frame 2 to scale on both X and Y, color of red.

So that when the window is resized the frame 1 keeps its x position and the frame 2 will scale.

As seen in picture below:
[Expected Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJdJu.png)

So this was the code used:

```
import tkinter as tk


frame1 = tk.Frame(bg = 'blue', width= 150, height = 150)
frame2 = tk.Frame(bg = 'red')
frame1.pack(fill = tk.Y, expand = 1, anchor = tk.W, side = tk.LEFT)
frame2.pack_propagate(True) 
frame2.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = 1, anchor = tk.E, side = tk.RIGHT)
```

Though it produces this: [Actual Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlHj4.png)

A requirement for this is I still need to use pack, but stuck on how to get the outcome required.

Answer (score 1):

Your only problem is that `frame1` needs `expand` to be set to `False` or `0`.

By setting it to `1`, you're asking Tkinter to expand the area given to the left frame. Since you only have it fill in the "y" direction, the frame on the left doesn't fill up that extra area even though it has been allocated, which is why you see the blank space between the left and the right side.

Answer (score -1):

fairly simple, if you want them to stack side by side you need to keep stacking them from the same side, and the first frame doesn't need `expand=1`

try the following:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

frame1 = tk.Frame(bg = 'blue', width= 150, height = 150)
frame2 = tk.Frame(bg = 'red')
frame1.pack(fill = tk.Y, anchor = tk.W, side = tk.LEFT)
frame2.pack_propagate(True) 
frame2.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = 1, anchor = tk.E, side = tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: FWIW, you don't need to stack them from the same side.